# HTML - space between divs

Tags: html, css

I have built my website from 3 divs but I have an annoying problem between my divs. I have some space I don't want. This is my website's markup:

```
  <div id="upbox">
    <h1 class="headline1">...</h1>
  </div>
      <div id="navig">

          <table align="center" cellspacing="0" width="60%" cellpadding="0" dir="ltr">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href =url> home </a></td>
                    <td><a href =url> Reviews </a></td>
                    <td><a href =url> Upcoming </a></td>
                    <td><a href =url> Xbox 360 </a></td>
                    <td><a href =url> Xbox One </a></td>
                    <td><a href =url> PS3 </a></td>
                    <td><a href =url> PS4 </a></td>
                    <td><a href =url> PC </a></td>
                    <td><a href =url> Contact Us </a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

      </div>
    <hr />

   <div id="mainbox">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p class="imgfirst"><img src="Images\characters.jpg" width="70%"></p>

   </div>
```

And my css is:

```
#mainbox {
  width: 1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #970c0c;
}

#upbox {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  clear:none;
}

#navig { background-color: #970c0c; }
```

I have tried everything but it does not help. What can I do?

This is my current result.

[image: screenshot of the annoying spacing]

Comment: Have you reset the browser default styles?

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to your CSS, as there are margins associated with your `h1`,`hr` and `body` elements:

```
h1 { margin:0; }
hr { margin:0; }
body { margin:0; }
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/4gq3b/3/

You might consider using a [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) stylesheet. Basically this is a way to keep results as universal as possible by defeating any browser-based rules and omissions before your CSS is applied.

Also, I presume you have a reason for setting `#mainbox { width:1000px; }`, it just looks a bit weird. All the `divs` will be the same width if you take out the `width` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to adjust the margins of block-level elements inside your divs:

```
 #upbox h1{ margin: 0; }
```

Obviously those breaks you have in `#mainbox` will create white space as well.

Answer (score 0):

The browser has CSS rules that it apply to web pages by default but the way each browser vendor decides to implement these rules are slightly different. So what you are experiencing are default rules from the browser.

To override these default rules from the browser and fix your problem you can put this line at the top of your CSS file. This will set margin for these three elements to 0.

```
h1, hr, body { margin: 0 }
```

Another option would be to include a CSS reset either at the top of your CSS file or link to one. Here are some resources that you can use to get your CSS to a baseline and you can build up from there: CSS Reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html and Normalize CSS: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Now lets talk about semantic HTML:

In your code you are using a table to hold what seems to be a navigation bar. A better option would be to to use an un-ordered list within your `div` or `nav` tag(which is supplied in html5) which will future proof and give you more flexibility.

HTML would look something like this.

```
 <div id ="navig">
   <ul>
     <li>Reviews</li>
     <li>Upcoming</li> 
     <li>Xbox 360</li> 
   </ul>
 </div>
```

or:

```
  <nav ="navig">
   <ul>
     <li>Reviews</li>
     <li>Upcoming</li> 
     <li>Xbox 360</li> 
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS would look something like this.

```
 #navig {
   background-color: #970c0c;
 }

 #navig ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
 }

 #navig ul li {
   display: inline;
 }
```

CSS tip: See how you wrote out the margin four times? It can be written in on line with the number corresponding to top, right, bottom, left: `margin: 0 0 0 0;`. And the clear relates to floated elements so you might be able to drop that too.

```
#upbox {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  /*four into one*/
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  clear:none;
}
```

Hope all this helps: Happy Coding!!